# Installing MySQL 5.6 Installer completely silent

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute the latest MySQL Community installer (mysql-installer-community-5.6.10.0.msi) silently, so I can then install it via the MySQLInstallerConsole.  This way I can deploy it using the Web Platform Installer (WebPI)

I tried with /q and /quiet but neither work - both cases launch the MySQLInstaller GUI

Ideas?

Comment: This is not exactly a problem that can be solved with code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that msi is interactive install only, it accepts the /quiet flag but ignores it. There may be some other way of forcing a quite install but its not in the docs. We might have to wait for an "essentials" msi from Oracle before we get quite install support back for 5.6.